# Provide Decimal Point Number to .toLocaleString() in TypeScript

Tags: string, typescript, casting, locale

I am trying to **form** a **number** having a decimal separator from a **string** in order to be able to apply .toLocaleString() method , which cannot be applied on strings.

```
const initialString = 122; //number
const decimalStr = initialString.toFixed(initialString); //string
const formattedStr = decimalStr.toLocaleString('de-DE');//error,decimalStr is a string
```

If any conversion is to be applied to the `decimalStr`, the decimal digits would be **lost** ( i.e. `decimalStr = +decimalStr` or `decimalStr = Number(decimalStr)`. => *problem, need to keep decimal digits.*

> How can i keep the decimal points and make the .toLocaleString()
>   see calling value as a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Number.toLocaleString` method accepts a second argument called `options`.
You can use this argument to control the number of fraction digits. Therefore, your call would be:

```
const initialNumber = 122; 
const formattedStr = initialNumber.toLocaleString('de-DE', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
```

For more details check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Also, notice that both `toFixed` and the `maximumFractionDigits` have limits: 100 and 20, respectively. So the example you provide fails on the second line.